# What does 이나 mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

국립공원은 산이나 바다로 이루어져 있어요

Both Naver and Google translate translate it as:
 - "National parks consist of mountain AND ocean"

이나 means "OR" though:
Shouldn't it be "Mountain OR ocean". ?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. 이나 should be OR, not AND. But let me say it's the inclusive OR, not the exclusive. So in your sample sentence 국립공원 can contain of only 산, only 바다, or 산 and 바다 together.

My explanation would be a bit different from strict definition in the dictionary ([Link to the Naver dictionary](https://ko.dict.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=30364900)). The dictionary says that 이나 should be exclusive OR, saying that

> (받침 있는 체언이나 부사어 뒤에 붙어) 둘 이상의 사물을 같은 자격으로 이어 주는 접속 조사. 나열되는 사물 중 하나만이 선택됨을 나타낸다.
>
> 바자회 물품으로 책이나 옷을 받고 있다.

However, often as it happens in the real life, the real usage of the word is different from the definition in the dictionary. Even in the sample sentence in the dictionary, nobody would be upset if I submit both 책 AND 옷 to 바자회!